# Rewrite a function from Parent theme on Child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on changing some stuff in a theme using a child theme I created.
There's a function in the parent theme that I want to change, and it doesn't sit in functions.php but in a file inside a subfolder (theme/admin/admin.php). 

how do I rewrite this function?
this is the original function (it needed):
http://www.codeshare.io/v5aTK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account that the function in the parent theme isn't wrapped in:

```
if( !function_exists('jtheme_home_sections_settings') ){ 
... 
}
```

it won't be possible to override it in your child theme (you will get a function is already defined error).

Comment: And if I wrap it? How will I do it then?
(I can always stick an admin memo to remember wraping it again in case of updating the parent theme....)

Comment: Then it should work - the `functions.php` file of your child theme is loaded before all the other functions of the parent theme so your function will override the parent one.